# index action for gem 'public_activity'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm using 'public_activity' gem to create activity feed. I've followed [**this tutorial**](http://railscasts.com/episodes/406-public-activity)

The tutorial shows you how to create activity feed for users who follow certain people.

```
class ActivitiesController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @activities = PublicActivity::Activity.order("created_at desc").where(owner_id: current_user.followed_user_ids, owner_type: "User")
  end

...
```

How can I add current_user's id, so that on index page he sees activity from people he is following plus his own?

Answer (score 1):

Could you make another variable and place it before the @activities variable in the index view?

Something like this is the controller:

```
class ActivitiesController < ApplicationController
  def index
@activities_current_user = PublicActivity::Activity.order("created_at desc").where(owner_id: current_user.id, owner_type: "User")
@activities = PublicActivity::Activity.order("created_at desc").where(owner_id: current_user.followed_user_ids, owner_type: "User")
  end
```

Then in the View:

```
<% @activities_current_user.each do |activity| %>
  <div class="activity">
    <%= link_to activity.owner.name, activity.owner if activity.owner %>
    <%= render_activity activity %>
  </div>
<% end %>

<% @activities.each do |activity| %>
  <div class="activity">
    <%= link_to activity.owner.name, activity.owner if activity.owner %>
    <%= render_activity activity %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```